# Basic parallax not working using stellar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, parallax

I've spent the past couple hours trying to solve what should be a really simple solution, but I'm banging my head against the wall and hoping someone here can spot what I'm missing.

Trying to make a featured image slider have a parallax effect to it (similar to [this](http://abduzeedo.com/daily-inspiration-1634)). I've called the stellar script in my header as follows:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/javascripts/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $.stellar();
});
</script>
```

This is the image slider that I want to scroll slower than the rest of the page (I'm using a custom fields plugin... that's what you'll see being called there):

```
<div class="featured-slider parallax" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"><?php the_field('featured_slider'); ?></div>
```

And here's the only CSS I've added to the element:

```
.parallax {
    position: relative;
}
```

Is there something more I should be doing? Am I missing something obvious?

[Here's the page where I'm trying to do this.](http://kellywongdesign.com/test/kierenmacmillan2/drunken-moon/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like on your page you are adding the script tag for stellar before jquery. You need the order to be Jquery, stellar, then your special script. Everything else you are doing looks correct.

```
//script tag for jquery
//script tag for stellar
//your script with stellar stuff.
```

Also Wordpress sometimes does not like the `$`. Use `jQuery` instead to initialize stellar and document ready.

Comment: Hmm... I think I've got it in that order. I had loaded it in my functions.php file. To be safe, I've put it in my header.php above all scripts as:

`code`<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>

Comment: I clicked good old view source and it was most certainly not in that order. Click the regular view source and check it out.

Comment: jquery steller line 24. jquery itself line 49.

Comment: You're right... I'm guessing wp_enqueue_script was trumped by the functions.php? Either way, I've moved stellar way down. Now it's on line 129, but still no parallax.

Comment: Now check your console log. Which now says:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.stellar.min.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`
You're getting somewhere.

Comment: Also if you are using wordpress it sometimes has issues with the `$`. Try using `jQuery(function(){` for the document ready of stellar. and `jQuery` for the initialization of `stellar`. Instead of the dollar sign.

Comment: That was what was giving it problems. I swapped the `$` for `jQuery(function(){` and it got rid of that error. There's another error (event.returnValue), but after Googling it, that one doesn't seem to be anything to worry about... Parallax still not working, though :( 

(Thanks for your patience with me... I'm a jQuery novice)

Comment: you still have :
`<script>
$(function() {
    $.stellar();
});
</script>`
Change those to `jQuery` not `$`

Comment: Are you looking at an old cache? This is the current version for me: `<script>jQuery(function() { jQuery.stellar(); });</script>`. I also tried `<script>jQuery(function() { $.stellar(); });</script>` to no luck and `<script>jQuery(function($) { $.stellar(); });</script>`

Comment: So congrats! It looks like it's working. Not how you want it but it is applying the effect. Go into google chrome dev tools and check the element you can see as you scroll it is changing the background position. Your issue of stellar js not applying is currently solved.

Comment: THANKS! :) I can take it from here. I appreciate your help @Johnston.